# Happy/YACC reducing when it should shift

Tags: yacc, shift-reduce-conflict, happy

I'm working on a parser and I'm really frustrated. In the language, we can have an expression like:

```
new int[3][][]
```

or

```
new int[3]
```

Most of it parses correctly, except for the empty arrays at the end.
In my parser I have:

```
Expression : int
             char
             null
             (...many others...)
             new NewExpression
```

and then a NewExpression is:

```
NewExpression : NonArrayType '[' Expression ']' EmptyArrays
              | NonArrayType '[' Expression ']'
```

and then EmptyArrays is one or more empty braces - if EmptyArrays derives the empty string, it adds 20 shift/reduce conflicts:

```
EmptyArrays : EmptyArrays EmptyArray
            | EmptyArray
EmptyArray  : '[' ']'
```

However, when I look in the `.info` file for the parser, I get this:

```
State 214¬
¬
▸   NewExpression -> NonArrayType lbrace Expression rbrace . EmptyArrays    (rule 80)¬
▸   NewExpression -> NonArrayType lbrace Expression rbrace .    (rule 81)¬
¬
▸   dot            reduce using rule 81¬
▸   ';'            reduce using rule 81¬
▸   ','            reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '+'            reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '-'            reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '*'            reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '/'            reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '<'            reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '>'            reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '<='           reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '>='           reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '=='           reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '!='           reduce using rule 81¬
▸   ')'            reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '['            reduce using rule 81    --I expect this should shift
▸   ']'            reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '?'            reduce using rule 81¬
▸   ':'            reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '&&'           reduce using rule 81¬
▸   '||'           reduce using rule 81
```

I expect though that if we're in state 214 and we see a left brace, we should shift it onto the stack and continue to parse EmptyArrays.

I'm not exactly sure what is going on because when I strip all of the excess out of the baggage (eg) by starting the parse with `NewExpression`, the additional brackets parse correctly. It's not possible for an Expression or a Statement or any non-terminal in the grammar to start with a left brace. Especially because I have a similar rule for if/else statements, which generates a shift/reduce conflict, but chooses to shift if the next token is an else (this problem is well documented).

Can you help me figure out what is going wrong? I really appreciate your help, I am really tilting at windmills trying to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a precedence set for '[' and/or ']' with something like `%left '['` which causes this behavior.  Remove that precedence declaration, and this will reveal the shift/reduce conflict you have here.  As for why its a shift/reduce conflict, you probably also have a rule:

```
Expression: Expression '[' Expression ']'
```

for an array access.  The problem being that since a `NewExpression` is an `Expression` it may be followed by an index like this, and when looking at the lookahead of '[', it can't tell whether that's the beginning of an index expression or the beginning of an `EmptyArray` -- that would require 2-token lookahead.

One thing you could try for this specific case would be to have your lexer do the extra lookahead needed here and recognize `[]` as a single token.

Comment: Yep, that turned out to be exactly the problem. I realized yesterday afternoon I was looking for the problem in the wrong place, and once I realized what the problem was, I actually derived the same solution - lex an empty array as one token. Thanks! This bug was killing me.